# MS-Access 2013 unable to remove .laccdb locking file

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is a long shot, but does any one know how to remove the lock file created by access 2013 file type ".laccdb".

I have an excel sheet which is connected to the access database via power query. The access database is on a shared drive. However even when this file is closed the locking file for the access database is not deleted.

When trying to remove the lock file it just says that unable to close as another program is using.

I've closed down the machine, removed all temp files, checked nothing is running and also checked in computer management within the administration tools. and checked for any open files.

I know the database should be split to stop this happening. however this is not my database, and the user refuses to split.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: I would try to delete it again, make sure you're cleaning up your resources in Excel and Access, and if that all fails, just create a new Database and copy everything over. This can sometimes be due to corruption (which sucks)

Answer (score 2):

You can open and read the lock file with a text editor (I use Notepad++); within the file you should find the computer name (or some similar identifier) of the one(s) who have it open. You could then take that name/number/whatever to IT and see if they can identify who the user is. You should be able to close it from their computer. Hope this helps.